# Validation in WPF DataGrid not working

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm tryin to get properties on a ViewModel validated in the DataGrid, but I'm running into a problem.

My XAML code looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Items">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Quantity" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ViewModel-objects in the Items-collection (based on the Caliburn.Micro Screen-class) has a property that looks like this:

```
public int Quantity
{
    get { return Section.Quantity; }
    set { Section.Quantity = value; }
}
```

This works great! If I enter "abc" in the cell where a Quantity should be, a red line is drawn around the textbox to indicate an error.

However I want to be able to manipulate the Quantity value a litle, so I'd like to use this code instead:

```
public string Quantity
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} pcs.", Section.Quantity); }
    set
    {
        var quantityAsText = value.Replace("pcs.", string.Empty).Trim();

        int quantity;
        if (int.TryParse(quantityAsText, out quantity))
        {
            Section.Quantity = quantity;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Quantity);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FormatException("Quantity must be a number!");
        }
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work. The FormatException is never caught and my app crashes...

I've tried modifying the binding to this without any positive result:

```
Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd either use a converter to take care of this kind of thing, or I'd just drop it.  How much effort do you want to spend worrying about people who try to type in "pcs."?

Comment: My example is greatly simplified, so it isn't really just "pcs." text I'm worried about, which I - in hindsight - maybe should have made clear. I just created this example to keep things simple.

Comment: Well, anyhow, this is what converters are for.  A similar situation is in the Properties window for a UIElement.  You have a Width and Height property.  They take doubles, which represent pixels, but in the Property editor you can enter a size in inches (11 in), which gets coverted to pixels.

Comment: @Will: You're right about the intended use of converters I guess. In my real code I have to validate againts a bunch of other properties, so I'd have to create multiple ValueConverters and MultiValueConverters and that's what I wanted to avoid. Also, in a MVVM situation I'd like the validation on the ViewModel insted of the View, where the converters would be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel should implement `IDataErrorInfo` and you use that interface to define your validation rules

The top google link returned [this site](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/), which shows a simple example of how its implemented.

Comment: I looked at this [acticle](http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2009/12/20/the-datagrid-and-the-input-string-is-not-in-a-correct-format-message-in-silverlight/) and that didn't say anything about IDataErrorInfo. Apperently validation isn't done the same way in Silverlight and WPF?

Comment: @kennethkryger I believe that article uses the default exception handling in WPF/Silverlight to display errors. Personally, I prefer to use `IDataErrorInfo` since it keeps all validation in a central location and doesn't rely on throwing exceptions to display an error.